# How to customize CakePHP pagination url?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

currently i am using cakephp version 2.5.3

I want to change my cakephp pagination url.

My current URL is `http://www.example.com/newsFeeds/ajax_news_feed/page:2` I need `http://www.example.com/newsFeeds/index/page:2`

My Code:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(' <<' . __('Previous  '), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
    //echo $this->Paginator->url(array('controller'=>'newsFeeds', 'action'=>'index'));
    //echo $this->Paginator->link('Sort by title on page 5', array('controller'=>'newsFeeds', 'action'=>'index'));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('  Next') . '>> ', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
?>
```

Above pagination is showing-

[image: tt]

When i am clicking `2` then the link is going to `http://www.example.com/newsFeeds/ajax_news_feed/my_post/page:2` but i need `http://www.example.com/newsFeeds/index/my_post/page:2`

Please tell me how to change controller and action in pagination?

Comment: did you try to make a url route on routes.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User `$this->Paginator->options`-

Code:

```
<?php
    $this->Paginator->options['url'] = array('controller' => 'newsFeeds', 'action' => 'index/my_post');
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(' <<' . __('Previous  '), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('  Next') . '>> ', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For cakephp 3 its a little bit different:

```
$this->Paginator->options([
    'url' => [
        'controller' => 'newsFeeds',
        'action' => 'index',
        'my_post']
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks dear for answering... :)

Answer (score 0):

First I used this one `$this->Paginator->options(array($this->passedArgs));`. But to change the controller and the action I used the below code.

```
<?php $url = array('controller' => 'customer_deposits', 'action' => 'accounting_bucket'); 
$this->passedArgs = array_merge($url, $this->passedArgs); 
$this->Paginator->options['url'] = $this->passedArgs;
```

By using this way, you can change the url and use the passed arguments with the changed url.